# How can I override the Response status text from a controller?

Tags: plugin-development, controller, modules, headers

I'm trying to set the statusText in a response, from a module controller.

E.g.:

```
<?php

namespace modules\appmodule\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\web\Response;

class StatusController extends \craft\web\Controller
{
  protected $allowAnonymous = true;

  public function actionCheck(): Response
  {
    $response = Craft::$app->getResponse();
    $response->format = $response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $response->setStatusCode(204, 'Healthy');

    return $response;
  }
}
```

However, the result still uses the default statusText "No Content", and still sets the format to text/html:

```
❯ curl  -I http://localhost:8089/actions/appmodule/status/check
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2019 18:49:31 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3
X-Powered-By: Craft CMS
```

Comment: It is working for me on Apache... `HTTP/1.1 204 Healthy`

Comment: Interesting! I'm on nginx, I wonder if there's some kind of setting that controls this…